# Performance of JMS Queue connections

Tags: spring, parallel-processing, spring-jms

In my spring batch, i'm using Oracle DB and IBM WMQ and implemented Atomikos Transaction management and Spring Partitioning.

Requirement is, need to read 2 million records from database and after processing, post the same messages(1 message size=2kb) into WMQ and update 2 million records in database as well.

Following is my code configuration.
Queue configuration:
`

```
<bean id="atomikosJmsConnectionFactory" class="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="WMQ_MQSeries_XA_RMI" />
        <property name="xaConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory">
                <property name="connectionNameList" value="127.0.0.1(1414)" />
                <property name="queueManager" value="LWMQ" />
                <property name="channel" value="LCHNL" />
                <property name="transportType">
                  <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT" />
                </property>
                <property name="clientReconnectOptions">
                  <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreSessionTransactedFlag" value="${mq.ignoreSessionTransactedFlag:false}"></property>
        <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="300"></property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"></property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="jmsTemplate"  class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="atomikosJmsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="0" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="2000" />
    </bean>
```

`

Spring Job Configuration:

```
<batch:step id="masterStep">
      <batch:partition step="slaveStep" partitioner="customPartitioner">
        <batch:handler task-executor="taskExecutor" />
      </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
      <batch:listener ref="loadJobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
  </batch:job>

  <batch:step id="slaveStep">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="atomikosTransactionManager">
      <batch:chunk chunk-completion-policy="chunkCompletionPolicy" />
    </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" >
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="L-Thread-"></property>
    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="20"></property>
  </bean>

 <bean id="chunkTimeout"
    class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.TimeoutTerminationPolicy">
    <constructor-arg value="36000" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="commitCount"
    class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.SimpleCompletionPolicy">
    <property name="chunkSize" value="100" />
  </bean>

<bean id="chunkCompletionPolicy"
    class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.CompositeCompletionPolicy">
    <property name="policies">
      <list>
        <ref bean="commitCount" />
        <ref bean="chunkTimeout" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Here is my linux server configuration:
Model : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU v4 @ 2.60GHz
Architecture: x86_64
No of CPU : 16
RAM : 100GB

Currently, the job takes 120 min to finish the task(including 2 million messages posting into MQ and updating into database)

my Observation: Most of the time Threads are in waiting state for MQ connection.
Following is the Visual-VM screenshot of threaddump.

```
"L-Thread-4" #101 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002349e000 nid=0xcabc waiting on condition [0x00000000324cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000771afc540> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.xs.xio.actor.impl.FutureImpl.await(FutureImpl.java:268)
    at com.ibm.ws.xs.xio.actor.impl.FutureImpl.get(FutureImpl.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.xsspi.xio.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.askAndGet(MessageDispatcher.java:373)
    at com.ibm.ws.xs.xio.actor.impl.ActorRefImpl.askAndGet(ActorRefImpl.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.client.XIOClientCoreMessageHandler.sendMessageInternal(XIOClientCoreMessageHandler.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.client.XIOClientCoreMessageHandler.sendMessage(XIOClientCoreMessageHandler.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.client.CommonClientCoreMessageHandler.sendGetRequest(CommonClientCoreMessageHandler.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.client.RemoteTransactionCallbackImpl.mapGet(RemoteTransactionCallbackImpl.java:1953)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.client.RemoteCacheLoader.get(RemoteCacheLoader.java:497)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.map.BaseMap.getRaw(BaseMap.java:4846)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.DiffMap.lookForKey(DiffMap.java:1391)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.DiffMap.get(DiffMap.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.ObjectMapImpl.get(ObjectMapImpl.java:451)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.ObjectMapImpl.get(ObjectMapImpl.java:411)
    at com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.spring.ObjectGridCache.get(ObjectGridCache.java:290)
```

How can i fix this issue to speed up my process..?

I need to finish this job process within 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `CachingConnectionFactory` to avoid opening a new connection for each send.

Comment: I have tried with CachingConnectionFactory earlier. I got a problem related to sessions closing. Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJMSException: error during enlist: Failed to suspend branch: XAResourceTransaction: 31302E3234362E38392E392E746D30303034323030303033:31302E3234362E38392E392E746D35
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)

Comment: Caused by: com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJMSException: error during enlist: Failed to suspend branch: XAResourceTransaction: 31302E3234362E38392E392E746D30303034323030303033:31302E3234362E38392E392E746D35
        at com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJMSException.throwAtomikosJMSException(AtomikosJMSException.java:55)

Comment: Caused by: com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.InvalidSessionHandleStateException: Failed to suspend branch: XAResourceTransaction: 31302E3234362E38392E392E746D30303034323030303033:31302E3234362E38392E392E746D35
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler.transactionSuspended(BranchEnlistedStateHandler.java:117)
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.transactionSuspended(TransactionContext.java:112)

Comment: Comments are not intended to provide information like that; you should edit the question instead. Try disabling session caching - you'll still get the benefit of using a shared connection.

Comment: @GaryRussell how can i disable session caching,I tried with o for sessionCacheSize.But it doesn't work .http://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default.asp?community.6.942

Comment: You can't with the CCF; use a `SingleConnectionFactory` if you only want a shared connection.

Comment: Same problem with SingleConnectionFactory.Here is example to reproduce this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327445/jms-doesnt-work-in-global-transaction-with-cachingconnectionfactory/46330181#46330181